# Сетка товаров на Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

У меня есть сетка товаров сделанная на гридах. Количество товаров в ряду - 4, рядов может неопределенное количество. При нажатии на какой-либо товар, под рядом, в котором находится товар, на всю ширину сетки должна появится его полная карточка, как бы добавить еще один ряд.

Как я вижу реализацию: считаю на какую по счету карточку нажали, после следующей карточки, счет которой кратный четырем, добавляю большую карточку. Но, так как в стилях прописано `grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 190px);` , то большая карта занимает только эти 190рх, а нужно, чтобы была на всю ширину сетки. Каким образом такое можно реализовать?

Пример кода:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 190px);
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
}

.item {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.card {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 700px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все нормально у вас, осталось довести до логического завершения:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 190px);
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
}

.item {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.card {
  background-color: #ccc;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: span 4;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

---

А вот так можно попробовать обойтись без подсчета каждой четвертой карты:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 190px);
  justify-content: space-between;
  grid-row-gap: 5px;
  grid-column-gap: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.selected {
  margin-bottom: 205px;
  background-color: pink;
}

.card {
  background-color: gold;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 205px;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: span 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item selected">
    <div class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="item"></div>

  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо!________

Comment: Пожалуйста. Добавил еще один способ, без подсчета карты.

Comment: И от меня спасибо, очень быстро помог выучить более оптимальный способ вывода товаров, нежели на флексах! Респект!